# How to style a row of lists of lists created with a Table and return all lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I want to return a list of all lists with elements in a single first list styled if it meets a condition so that it stands out from other lists. My attempt at this only returns all data with no row styled. Here is what i have...

```
eqs = {eqn = S'[t] + .1 S[t] == 0, ic = S[0] == 30000};
sol = DSolve[eqs, S[t], t][[1, 1, 2]];
raw = Table[{t, sol}, {t, 0, 15}];
yr = Select[raw, #[[2]] < 8000 &, 1][[1, 1]];
data = MapAt[PaddedForm[#, {5, 2}] &, raw, {All, 2}];
Map[Style[#, Bold, Green] &, data[[yr + 1]]] (* proof of concept *)
data = Replace[data, 
data[[yr + 1]] -> Map[Style[#, Bold, Green] &, data[[yr + 1]]]]
```

Comment: `Map[Style[#, Bold, Green] &, data[[yr + 1]]]`?

Comment: thank you. that solves the curly brackets not getting highlighted when applied as you suggested but when inserted in `data = Replace[...]` it returns the data with no row highlighted.

Comment: Did the answer I posted do what you want? Not sure what you mean by "return all lists".

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi in case you missed it i had edited my comment. here is the edited comment:

thank you. that solves the curly brackets not getting highlighted when applied as you suggested but when inserted into `data = Replace[...->Map[...]]` it returns the original data with no row highlighted.

Comment: Added image to the answer. Do you see something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data // ReplacePart[yr + 1 -> Map[Style[#, Bold, Green] &, data[[yr + 1]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. that worked. i have just one question. how could i have written it without postfix notation (`//ReplacePart[...]`)?

Comment: I used the operator form of `ReplacePart`. I find it easier to understand and edit expressions in postfix form rather than deal with deeply nested square brackets. `ReplacePart[data, 
 yr + 1 -> Map[Style[#, Bold, Green] &, data[[yr + 1]]]]`.